# Tomcat 7 AccessLogValve maxDays not deleting access log files

Tags: apache, tomcat, logging, access-log

I added the maxDays attribute to the AccessLogValve node of a Tomcat 7 server.xml, but access log files have not been deleted after restarting tomcat or restarting the Linux server.  Am I missing something?  The AccessLogValve config is:

```xml
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
    directory="logs" 
    prefix="site_access." 
    suffix=".log" 
    maxDays="7" 
    resolveHosts="false" 
    pattern="%{org.apache.catalina.AccessLog.RemoteAddr}r %l %u" />
```

Comment: In the end, nothing worked and we just used a cron job to delete out old log files

Comment: Adding the `maxDays` param and restarting tomcat worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still dealing with an ancient Tomcat installation: be aware that the `maxDays` property was only added in **v7.0.86**.
This is not clear at all from the configuration docs or the Javadoc, i had to git-blame it myself from the repo.

In previous versions, you get this message in `catalina.<date>.log` :

```
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Valve} Setting property 'maxDays' to '180' did not find a matching property.
```

Here is the commit that added the `maxDays` property:

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/f9a4657b1d5b0284b1f6b99688db84ea273b8f28

And this is the related BugZilla entry (see comment 9):

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52688#c9